# Сериализация списка объектов

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Есть объект класса ExcelStylesheet, который подлежит сериализации в JSON.

```
public class ExcelStylesheet
{        
    public Dictionary<int, uint> CellFormatIndexes { get; set; }        
    public List<Font> Fonts { get; set; }        
    public List<CellFormat> CellFormats { get; set; }        
    public List<Fill> Fills { get; set; }        
    public List<Border> Borders { get; set; }
}
```

Пытаюсь сериализовать в файл.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stylesheet);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
```

На выходе получаю:

```
{"CellFormatIndexes": {"0": 9,"1": 10},"Fonts": [[[],[]],[[],[],[]]],"CellFormats": [[[]],[[]]],"Fills": [[]],"Borders": [[]]}
```

Почему списки объектов сериализуются таким образом и как сделать нормальную сериализацию?

Используемая библиотека: `Newtonsoft.Json`. Списки из объектов классов библиотеки `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что все эти классы наследуют от `OpenXmlElement`, который является коллекцией дочерних элементов. Newtonsoft.Json все такие классы сохраняет как массивы.

Если вам нужно записать объект в файл для последующего чтения - лучше преобразуйте эти объекты в строку через OuterXml при записи, а при чтении преобразуйте обратно через принимающий строку конструктор.

Можете попытаться написать свой `JsonConverter` для наследников `OpenXmlElement`.

Comment: Как правильно тогда сериализовать объект данного класса, если часть его полей надо отправлять в xmlserializer,  а другая часть уже как бы серализована и их просто надо "вложить" в полученный сериализованный объект?